# Return the row, when Unique key voliation happens

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to return the record, that causes the unique key violation in MSSQL, When inserting data?

Comment: From where are you making these insert calls?

Comment: You can tweak the query you're doing the insert with to just `SELECT` any rows already matching your keys instead (this needs a transaction to work reliably if there are many concurrent changes). Alternatively, if you have a recent version of SQL Server, it'll put the key (well, *a* key) in the error message ("the duplicate key value is") that you could catch and parse, but that's not particularly elegant.

Comment: Bear in mind that SQL Server will bail out at the *first* violation. Even knowing which row caused the error may lead to a frustrating "try, try again" experience if you were trying to insert, say, 100 rows and 50 of them are duplicates.

Comment: Also, there might be more than one column causing a unique key violation.

Comment: In my case, My app inserts only one record at a time, Just want to fetch the entire row in the database for duplication. ( and there is only one column applied unique key constraint)

Comment: In your case first read the table if there are any rows with the same unique value. Use Exists in SQL.

Comment: Actually, The table is going to grow with time. So I want to skip table reading.  I have made the unique constraint for one column ( that I am specifically concerned). My idea is to try inserting, if the value is not unique, return the existing record with that value.

Comment: Your unique constraint is backed by an index, and that index is already going to be read as part of the insert. A successful insert will modify the index, which is even more expensive. An extra index lookup in case of a violation isn't going to break the bank, no matter where it occurs in the process (unless violations are very common, but then *that* is a cause for concern). Be wary of optimizing things prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this schema

```
select * from 
(
   --query used for your insert

) f1
where exists 
(
   select * from tablewhereyouwantinsert f2
   where f1.key1=f2.key1 and f1.key2=f2.key2 ---- keys used into your unique key violation

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to conditionally insert or retrieve a row from the database using a single statement.

Unfortunately, to get the retrieval action, we do have to touch the existing row, I'm assuming that's acceptable and that you'll be able to construct a low impact "No-Op" `UPDATE` as below:

```
create table T (ID int not null primary key, Col1 varchar(3) not null)
insert into T(ID,Col1) values (1,'abc')

;merge T t
using (values (1,'def')) s(ID,Col1)
on t.ID = s.ID
when matched then update set Col1 = t.Col1
when not matched then insert (ID,Col1) values (s.ID,s.Col1)
output inserted.*,$action;
```

This produces:

```
ID          Col1 $action
----------- ---- ----------
1           abc  UPDATE
```

Including the `$action` column helps you know that this was an existing row rather than the `insert` of `(1,def)` succeeding.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd really use a `MERGE` here instead of separate statements with a transaction, but assuming we go with that, I suggest changing the update clause to `SET @dummy = NULL` (with `@dummy` a variable we declared earlier). This *still* performs a logical update operation, but at least does not produce physical writes.